# How to pass arguments to controller in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I am currently coding a simple forum website using the mean stack.  I Am at the point where I am displaying the content of a given topic.  To do this I am using an ng-model so that the user enters the name of the topic and then I query my mongodb.  The problem is after a refresh the user has to enter the name again to get the desire content. How can I code so that the user selects a topic and the proper content gets displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll let you fill in the blanks for what you need (or you can ask further questions), but here is some basic code from the Angular side of things to hit an endpoint and retrieve some data and display it in a view.

You'll need [UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) as described in Gustavo's answer.

**App** - the config in here will allow you to refresh the page and still be able to keep the topic that you want.

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('topics', {
      url: '/topics/:topic',
      templateUrl: 'path_to_template.html',
      controller: 'myController'
    });
  });
```

**Service** - this will talk to your API which will grab the data for you.

```
angular.module('app')
  .service('myService', function($http) {
    this.getInfo = function(topic) {
      return $http.get('path_to_api', { params: { topic: topic } });
    };
  });
```

**Controller** - this will be what binds your template to your scope which will allow you to display results.

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('myController', function($scope, $stateParams, myService) {
    activate();

    function activate() {
      myService.getInfo($stateParams.topic)
        .then(function(result) {
          $scope.topicInfo = result;
        });
    }
  });
```

Hope this helps - happy to answer any other questions you may have.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the data after refresh you should integrate your arguments as parameters in the url using angular-ui-router (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

```
.state('topics', {
    url: '/topics/:search',
    templateUrl: 'html',
    controller: 'Controller'
  })
```

And then inside the controller you get the params with $stateParams:

```
var search = $stateParams.search;
```

This should give you a head start, hope it helps =)